# how can I insert date in mysql query?

Tags: java, java-time

I am trying to save date and time in the attribute of `datetime` type (`'0000-00-00 00:00'`). I used the following code. But error - `HTTP Status 500 - Internal Error` comes up, because of `line 6` displaying the following error message:
`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-04-30 23:59 could not be parsed at index 10`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
LocalDateTime forDate = LocalDateTime.parse(newDate, formatter);
out.println(forDate);
ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reminder_logs VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)");
ps.setInt(1, r_id);                        
ps.setDate(2, forDate);
i = ps.executeUpdate();
```

**Edited:** Error - HTTP Status 500 - Internal Error
[image: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Error]

I tried to use `setTimestamp(2, forDate)` instead of `setDate(2, forDate)` but then I got an error saying - incompatible types : `LocalDateTime` cannot be converted to `Timestamp`.
I tried to take references from the below links but none of them helped:

1. [java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-2-2' could not be parsed at index 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878574/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-2016-2-2-could-not-be-parsed-at)
2. [How to set current date and time using prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626076/how-to-set-current-date-and-time-using-prepared-statement)
3. [Unparseable date error on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325522/unparseable-date-error-on-java)

What can I do to solve this error?
I am running java se 8.

Comment: afaik, the format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: but I dont want seconds, so what should I do?

Comment: Just add `:00`?

Comment: but `newDate` is coming from another jsp page in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format..

Comment: The MySQL [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) field includes the seconds, so do what @tadman suggested, and append `:00` to your format string.

Comment: The error is still persistent because of the statement `ps,setDate(2, forDate)`. I am using Netbeans IDE 8.1. `forName` is displayed with an underline with an error saying - `incompatible types : LocalDateTime cannot be converted to Date`.

Comment: How can i insert timestamp using the above code..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` is the fact that you are using `hh` instead of `HH` in your format string.

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
```

Following which you give a 24h formatted timestamp.

```
// runnable example

String newDate = "2017-04-30 23:59";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
LocalDateTime forDate = LocalDateTime.parse(newDate, formatter);
System.out.println(forDate);
```

Results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-04-30 23:59' could not be parsed: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 23
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at _Scratchpad.SO.main(SO.java:12)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 23
....
```

This trace clearly shows that the time is out of range:

> Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 23

Comment: Even after editing `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")` to `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`, the error in the above image is still persistent.